# Listview with checkboxes to delete sqlite rows? WPF, C#

Tags: wpf, sqlite, listview

Learning WPF and coming from Windows forms!

I am currently doing the following to load a database, however I'd also like to know how to bind checkboxes to the selected event for listview's items and delete the selected row from a sqlite database and listview after a button click.

Edit: thanks to the help of AVK Naidu, it's now working!

```
   public ObservableCollection<MyItem> myItems { get; set; }
   public class MyItem
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Key1 { get; set; }
        public string Key2 { get; set; }
        public string Key3 { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }
    private void LoadDatabaseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myItems = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();
        SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection;
        m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");
        m_dbConnection.Open();
        SQLiteCommand readdatabase = new SQLiteCommand("Select * From TableName", m_dbConnection);
        using (SQLiteDataReader read = readdatabase.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (read.Read())
            {
                listView4.Items.Add(new MyItem { Key = read["Key"].ToString(), Key2 = read["Key2"].ToString(), Key3 = read["Key3"].ToString(), Key4 = read["Key4"].ToString() });
            }
        }
        m_dbConnection.Close();
    }
```

Here's my listview in XAML for loading the database:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="186" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="432" BorderBrush="Gray">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn Header="Key" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Key}"/>
          <GridViewColumn Header="Key1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Key1}"/>
          <GridViewColumn Header="Key2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Key2}"/>
          <GridViewColumn Header="Key3" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Key3}"/>

        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
      </ListView>
```

Delete from database:

```
        private void RemoveRowButton_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (var Checkboxitem in myItems)
        {
                if (Checkboxitem.IsSelected == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(Checkboxitem.Key.ToString() + Checkboxitem.Key1.ToString() + Checkboxitem.Key2.ToString() + Checkboxitem.Key3.ToString());
                }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you already create a listview with your template to show your 4 Keys? If yes, can you post that code?

Comment: @AVKNaidu Alright, added it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `MyItem` to below.

```
public class MyItem
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Key1 { get; set; }
    public string Key2 { get; set; }
    public string Key3 { get; set; }
}
```

In your GridView add a CheckBox Column. Your ListView will be something like Below.

```
<ListView x:Name="listView4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="Gray">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Key" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Key}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Key1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Key1}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Key2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Key2}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Key3" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Key3}"/>               
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

If you look at the `CheckBox` from `GridViewColumn.CellTemplate`, I made the Mode=TwoWay so that it can update the collection from which you are binding the data to.

So for a sample data like below,

```
myItems = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    myItems.Add(new MyItem() { Key = i.ToString(), Key2 = i.ToString(), Key1 = i.ToString(), Key3 = i.ToString(), IsSelected = false });
}
listView4.ItemsSource = myItems;
```

If you revisit your myItems on Delete Button Click, you can see that your actual collection's `IsSelected` will be updated to `true` if the checkbox is checked. Now you can iterate through your Collection and delete those records where `IsSelected` is `true`.

Comment: Thank you, lots of good information here. I am trying to get it to work, and using what you mentioned but it's not werkin'. I updated my example :) Right now when I actually go to show a checked item in message box, I get "ProjectName.MainWindow+MyItem".

Comment: Change it to Checkbox.Key.ToString()

Comment: I must've rearranged everything 20 times before I noticed that. Thank you very much!